# How can I free only part of an array using pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, free, realloc

My program contains records that include a first name, last name, and a grade. I need to write a function that allows the user to enter a last name, and will delete any record with that last name. I can only use pointers and simple memory allocation functions. For example, my records could look something like this:

`Smith, Will, 63`

`Crews, Terry, 30`

`Brady, Tom, 92`

The format here is lastName, firstName, grade.
I have two 2D char arrays to hold all of the names, and a float array to hold the scores.
If the user wanted to remove any record with the last name "Crews", my program would need to delete the entire name and score associated with that last name. So my record list would then look like:

`Smith, Will, 63`

`Brady, Tom, 92`

Here is what I have right now.

```
void delete_record(int size, char** firstName, char** lastName, float* score)
{
    int x;
    char *target = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter a last name. \n");
    printf("Any students with that last name will have their record deleted. \n");
    scanf("%s", target);

    for(x=0;x<size;x++)
    {
        if(strcmp(target, lastName + (x*15)) == 0)
        {            
            free(firstName);
            free(lastName);
            free(score);            
        }
    }
}
```

Edit to show arrays being defined

```
char **lastName = (char **)malloc(numOfRecords * sizeof(char));
```

numOfRecords is given by the user to determine the size of the list.

Comment: If the part to be "deleted" is contiguous, you can use `realloc`. If not contiguous AND you want to reduce the space taken, then you have two options: (1) Make new array and copy only needed elements. (2) Maintain an array of "holes" telling which indices are marked deleted.

Comment: @sxsa Show for example how the array of last names is defined.

Comment: Have you considered using a different data-structure  that is designed to better handle removal of interior items?  Perhaps a Linked-List or a Tree or the like?  You probably should also be packaging related data together in a struct rather than maintaining separate arrays of each datum.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons sadly for this example i'm not able to use a linked-list, struct, or anything like that.

Comment: Can you at least use a struct for easier management?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow just edited it now at the end of the post.

Comment: I would still recommend packaging your data into a struct.  something like `struct record { char *firstname; char *lastname; float score;};`.  Then you can make an array of `struct record`

Comment: @jiveturkey cant use structs either. i've looked at a ton of examples and there seem to be a ton of easier ways to manage this problem but for this example im limited to what ive shown here.

Comment: The code you just edited in is incorrect.  if you are creating a `char **`, then you should be `malloc`ing based on the `sizeof (char *)`, not `sizeof(char)`.  You can automate using the size of the correct object by dereferencing the object being allocated: `char **lastname = malloc(numOfRecords * sizeof(*lastname));`

Comment: Yeah, you're also free'ing a pointer instead of the lastname, firstname. `free(*lastname)`

Comment: You're passing a `char **` to `strcmp` which is wrong --- turn on warnings in your compiler and PAY ATTENTION TO THEM.  Your malloc call defining the array is also nonsensical, with pretty much no way it can work.